# Setting a folder object through a string describing its path

Tags: vba, object, outlook

In MS Outlook (2016) I am working on a VBA procedure to more quickly archive certain, individually selected e-mails into certain folders in my e-mail archive.

I have a procedure that does the trick when I address the target folder manually:

```
'[...]
Dim MoveToFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
'[...]
Set MoveToFolder = ns.Folders("Archive").Folders("Projekte-Archiv").Folders("P03_NetRef")
'[...]
```

With this the procedure knows what folder to move pre-selected e-mail to.

**Now my problem:**

I am trying to set the "MoveToFolder" folder object **through a string variable** giving it all the necessary data.

Why do I want to do this: Handing over the folder data as a string variable would allow me to use the same procedure for as many folders in as many hierarchy levels I want.

Here is what I came up with, using the CType function:

```
'[...]
Dim MoveToFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
'[...]
Set MoveToFolder = CType("ns.Folders(""Archive"").Folders(""Projekte-Archiv"").Folders(""P03_NetRef"")", Outlook.MAPIFolder)
'[...]
```

(The idea is of course in a next step to insert the string through a variable, not in plain writing like the example.)

This does not work. The object type 'Outlook.MAPIFolder' results in an error on compiling ("method or data object not found").

**Later insight**

As I understood later on, the CType() function is not available in VBA (as opposed to VB.net).

Comment: I have not run your code but when it works, what does the target folder resolve to? When it does not work what does the target folder resolve to?

Comment: Abstract that part out to a standalone function which you can pass something like "Archive|Projekte-Archiv|P03_NetRef"  Within the functon, split the path on "|" and loop over the folders, using each one to get the next.

Comment: @peakpeak  I hope this answers your question: When I run the procedure in the working version, the MoveToFolder gets loaded with all the data of such an object (folder object), including the folder path, here: "\\Archive\Projekte-Archiv\P03_NetRef", as one can see in the Locale Window. In the non-working version it does not get there at all because the problem occurs earlier, already during compilation. "Outlook.MAPIFolder" seems not to be an accepted object type in CType(). The question is, how can I then set MoveToFolder to a folder (path) that I provide in form of a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested:

```
Set MoveToFolder = GetFolder(ns, "Archive|Projekte-Archiv|P03_NetRef")
```

A function to parse the path:

```
Function GetFolder(root, fpath)
    Dim f As Object
    Dim arr, i
    arr = Split(fpath, "|")
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        If i = 0 Then
            Set f = root.Folders(arr(i))
        Else
            Set f = f.Folders(arr(i))
        End If
    Next i
    Set GetFolder = f
End Function
```

Comment: Works like a charm! - Interestingly, with this you did not actually answer the narrower question: "Can the CType() function made work with the object type 'Outlook.MAPIFolders'?" Rather you provided a solution that even saves me the time to develop something like this myself as this was where I wanted to go in the long run without knowing exactly how. Now I know. Very elegant solution!

Comment: `CType()` can't work because that's not even part of the VBA language.  That's .NET I think.

Comment: Hm. Perhaps I got confused because Microsoft mentions it in a Visual Basic guide... somewhere inside of a Dotnet topic: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/ctype-function